# How can I make a view selection independent from SelectionProvider?

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-rcp

I got a EMF Tree Viewer and a TableView which gets all objects from this Tree Viewer of a specific class. What I would like to do is to synchronize the TableView row selection with the corresponding object in the Tree Viewer, also opening its Properties View.

I tried setting a registry as ISelectionProvider and then `getViewSite().setSelectionProvider(registry);` also using a wrapper as IPropertySheetPage.

The main problem is that my TableView selection is now weird (when I click, the selection is just a blue border around the row, and in the second click the selection is normal) and I guess it is because the TableView also listens to my selection provider. Is there any way to bypass that? I am currently using a JavaFX TableView.

Weird selection:

[image: Weird Selection]

Selection in second click:

[image]

In createPartControl:

```
view.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    List<Object> eoList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (SimpleRow row : view.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
        if (null != row.getEObject())
            eoList.add(row.getEObject());
    }
    ;

    MinimalPlugin.getDefault().getRegistry().setSelection(new StructuredSelection(eoList));
});
getViewSite().setSelectionProvider(MinimalPlugin.getDefault().getRegistry());
```

At getAdapter:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
    if (adapter == IPropertySheetPage.class) {
        if (null == propertyPage)
            propertyPage = new PropertySheetWrapper();
        return propertyPage;
    }
    return super.getAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The EMF Tree Viewer selection listener:

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
win.getActivePage().addSelectionListener(new ISelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        if (selection instanceof StructuredSelection) {
            StructuredSelection sel = (StructuredSelection) selection;
            if (sel.getFirstElement() instanceof EObject) {
                // Get property sheet page from editor
                if (part instanceof IEditorPart) {
                    editorPart = (IEditorPart) part;
                    IPropertySheetPage newPropertyPage = editorPart.getAdapter(IPropertySheetPage.class);
                    if (null != newPropertyPage && newPropertyPage instanceof ExtendedPropertySheetPage) {
                        propertyPage.setPropertySheetPage((ExtendedPropertySheetPage) newPropertyPage);
                    }
                }

                EObject object = (EObject) sel.getFirstElement();
                EObject root = EcoreUtil.getRootContainer(object);
                populateFromRoot(root);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

populateFromRoot() method just redraws the TableView with found objects.

Comment: That is probably a focus-related thing...

Comment: To add to what fabian said - the two selections are the same, but the default JavaFX CSS defines a slightly different look when the `TableView` is focused vs. not-focused. This makes sense most of the time, as for example clicking the "down" arrow should go to the next item in the focused node (tree or table), so you want to know which is focused.